# clang-tidy-10 and compile_commands.json does not support relative paths

Tags: c++, clang-tidy

There are various posts about this - but I can't seem to find a definitive answer. Some people are saying it works and others not, and yet others saying its tools / IDEs that are the issue.

So I made as small an example as I could. Here are the two files I have:

### compile_commands.json

```json
[
    {
        "arguments": [ "gcc", "test.cpp" ],
        "directory": "/home/user/development/sandbox/comp_commands",
        "file": "test.cpp"
    }
]
```

#### test.cpp

```cpp
bool is_it()
{
    // no return value - give clang warning
}
```

Now if I run the command `clang-tidy test.cpp` in the same directory as the files I get:

```
[user] comp_commands$ clang-tidy test.cpp 
1 warning generated.
test.cpp:4:1: warning: non-void function does not return a value [clang-diagnostic-return-type]
}
```

... as expected. However if I change the line in the compile_commands.json directory to:

```json
        "directory": ".",
```

Then I get the output:

```
[user] comp_commands$ clang-tidy test.cpp 
Skipping /home/user/development/sandbox/comp_commands/test.cpp. Compile command not found.
```

[here](https://github.com/MaskRay/ccls/issues/703) "MaskRay"s answer suggests this is fine/works. Since I am using no IDE, just clang-tidy directly- it can't be the IDE...

Is it possible to use relative paths in the compile_commands.json file? - I am generating this file via a script and can use either, but I specifically want it to be relative paths.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Short answer

**No**, the `directory` in `compile_commands.json` cannot be relative.  It must be absolute to work with `clang-tidy`.

### What the spec says

The [specification](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/JSONCompilationDatabase.html)
for `compile_commands.json` says:

> - **directory**: The working directory of the compilation. All paths specified in the **command** or **file** fields must be either absolute or relative to this directory.

That is not very explicit, but as it acknowledges the possibility of
relative paths in other attributes, while saying nothing about a
relative `directory`, this is weak evidence that the path must be
absolute.

### What the source says

The code that prints `Compile command not found.` is in
[`ClangTool`](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1tooling_1_1ClangTool.html)`::run`:

```
std::vector<CompileCommand> CompileCommandsForFile =
    Compilations.getCompileCommands(File);
if (CompileCommandsForFile.empty()) {
  llvm::errs() << "Skipping " << File << ". Compile command not found.\n";
  FileSkipped = true;
  continue;
}
```

This is calling [`JSONCompilationDatabase`](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1tooling_1_1JSONCompilationDatabase.html)`::getCompileCommands`,
which consults the `MatchTrie` member, which is built in
`JSONCompilationDatabase::parse`, and includes these key lines:

```
if (!Directory) {
  ErrorMessage = "Missing key: \"directory\".";
  return false;
}
SmallString<8> FileStorage;
StringRef FileName = File->getValue(FileStorage);
SmallString<128> NativeFilePath;
if (llvm::sys::path::is_relative(FileName)) {
  SmallString<8> DirectoryStorage;
  SmallString<128> AbsolutePath(                       // (1)
      Directory->getValue(DirectoryStorage));
  llvm::sys::path::append(AbsolutePath, FileName);     // (2)
  llvm::sys::path::native(AbsolutePath, NativeFilePath);
} else {
  llvm::sys::path::native(FileName, NativeFilePath);
}
```

Although this code is willing to handle a relative `FileName`, the
`Directory` value is simply assumed to be absolute at (1), as its value
(as a YAML string) is concatenated with `FileName` at (2) and the result
treated as absolute from then on.

When the input file name `test.cpp` is passed on the command line,
the tooling infrastructure turns that into the absolute path
`/home/user/development/sandbox/comp_commands/test.cpp`, then
compares it as a string (via `MatchTrie`) to the path built by the above code,
which will be `./test.cpp` and hence not match.

### What about ccls?

[ccls](https://github.com/MaskRay/ccls) is a separate project that
happens to also consume the `compile_commands.json` format, but with an
[extension to allow relative `directory` attributes](https://github.com/MaskRay/ccls/issues/572#issuecomment-621295215).

That extension is not present in `clang-tidy`.

Comment: This is such a good answer, feels like it would be an easy patch for me to make if I had the inclination... but also begs the question - in an otherwise sophisticated tool.... why doesn't it handle relative dirs : (    (also a few other grips with clang tools like specifying the location of `.clang-format` and `.clang-tidy` files - all so easy to solve! :)